# What is the meaning of "contribute" in the following context

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *contribute* here?

> Plug-ins can **contribute** actionSets extensions that define actions with an
>   ID, a label, an icon, and a class that implements the interface IActionDelegate.
>   The UI will present that label and icon to the user, and when the user clicks on
>   the item, the UI will instantiate the given action class, cast it to IActionDelegate,
>   and call its run() method.

Comment: [Contribute](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contribute?q=contribute). It means the same as anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Contribute* means *supply* or *provide* in the quoted sentence.  *[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contribute#Verb)* shows the following definition:

> To give something, that is or becomes part of a larger whole

A plugin is code that can be loaded or merged on the fly into an existing program.  Plugins are used to add new capabilities to  existing programs.  The particular plugins the quote refers to can add multiple `actionSet` extensions, from which the user then can pick and choose.

Answer (score 0):

To give or supply in common with others.

A plug-in supplies an actionSets extension (in common with all of the other sources of actionSets extensions.)